# Prime Modal will not open

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, primeng

I have created a prime NG modal in Angular 2. It should open when a button is clicked which calls out to the toggleDeleteModalDisplay method below, but it doesn't seem to open. Not sure what i am doing wrong as i have other modals in the code which are basically the same

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'delete-user',
    templateUrl: './delete-user.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class DeleteUserComponent {

    public deleteModalDisplay : boolean = false;

    public toggleDeleteModalDisplay() : void {
           this.deleteModalDisplay = !this.deleteModalDisplay;
    }

}
```

```html
<p-dialog [(visible)]="deleteModalDisplay" [width]="500"
          [draggable]="false" [modal]="true" [dismissableMask]="true"
          class="delete-user-modal">
    <p-header class="header-modal">
        Delete User
    </p-header>
</p-dialog>
```

```js
import { DeleteUserComponent } from './delete-user/delete-user.component';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './manage-users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./manage-users.component.less'],
})
export class ManageUsersComponent {
    constructor(public deleteUserComponent: DeleteUserComponent) {}

    public deleteUser() : void {
      this.deleteUserComponent.toggleDeleteModalDisplay();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `this.deleteModalDisplay = !this.deleteModalDisplay;` will be easier to toggle the boolean value. I can't get my head around the tertiary operator usage here.

Comment: Can you add the button that calls `toggleDeleteModalDisplay()` Is it in the same component?

Comment: I updated the code to use - this.deleteModalDisplay = !this.deleteModalDisplay. Still seems to be the same issue. this.deleteModalDisplay is being changed to true whenever the button is clicked so it should appear. Also, i set the variable to be initialised as true - public deleteModalDisplay : boolean = false;, and the modal appears.

Comment: The button that calls the method is in a different component but it is hitting the method as i set a breakpoint

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: If the button that calls the method is in a different component how are these components related? Are they parent-child? you will have to show the code of both components and how they relate in the template for anyone to comment on this.

Comment: They are 2 sibling components. I have added the code where it calls out to the toggleDeleteModalDisplay method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the DeleteUserComponent you're calling `toggleDeleteModalDisplay()` on is not the one that's in your view. Unless you're passing an instance of your component into your ManageUsersComponent, it's injecting a new one via its constructor that's separate from the one on your view.

Instead of injecting a DeleteUserComponent in the constructor, try using a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

```
export class ManageUsersComponent {

    @ViewChild(DeleteUserComponent) deleteUserComponent: DeleteUserComponent;

    constructor() {}

    public deleteUser() : void {
      this.deleteUserComponent.toggleDeleteModalDisplay();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, sorry I didn't update this post earlier but what @jon said was the issue, the instance of toggleDeleteModalDisplay() that I was calling was not the one in the view. I ended up moving it to a service and it worked. Thanks everyone for the replies